# Chrome Copy Arbitary Text To ClipBoard to Send to AHK

Tags: javascript, autohotkey

I am attempting to use the clipboard to share text between Chrome and an AHK script. Specifically, I want to copy the ID of the currently focused element on the HTML page. Chrome does not let me use COM to access the currently focused element, so I'm forced to get "creative" (yuck).

This is not working (gives me a clipboardData is not defined error):

```
javascript:clipboardData.setData(window.document.activeElement.id);
```

Does anyone have any input on how to get this data to the clipboard so I can use the information in my AHK script?

Comment: How do you run that code in Chrome? I think clipboard access is restricted and is allowed only for a userscript or an extension with corresponding permissions set in metablock or manifest.json

Comment: I was attempting to paste the exact text above into the URL bar. Stupid, yes, but I need to get pass data between Chrome and AHK.

Comment: If you want to grab the text from an already existing selection, just send `^c`, wait for 10 ms or use ClipWait and read the clipboard.

Comment: I don't want to grab an existing selection. I want to use Javascript in the browser to get the id of an object (which is not selected) and put it on the clipboard to be accessed by AHK.

Comment: I think you'll have to write a userscript or an extension.

Comment: You can also try to communicate via window title...JS: `document.title` and AHK: `WinGetTitle`